# How to fix blurry images on pixelated (16x16) textures on Blender 3.3

Tags: modeling, texturing

I would like to make a render of my Minecraft world, however, the textures are sort of fuzzy and I was wondering if someone could help me fix it. I have heard from other posts and videos that it might be a mipmap issue, however, I am new to Blender and have no idea where that setting would be. It is not where it used to be like in the posts or videos about the subject on Blender 2.8. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thank you in advance. (Also there is another problem I don't know how to fix, but haven't really looked into so far, is that some of the 3D blocks [Like the grindstones and lanterns], one of the sides doesn't render, which is really odd. I am just saying because that is another issue that is in the picture.)[image: Blender Image of the Problem]

Answer (score 0):

By default, texture nodes have an interpolation so that eventual low resolution textures don't look too much blocky from close distance:

[image: interp]

Set it to closest to remove any interpolation:

[image: closest]

For your other issue, that seems unrelated. Please write another post giving more detail about it and providing an example file with packed textures so that people can investigate.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.
And about that other issue, I know it is unrelated, I just wanted whomever to know that that was an issue. I didn't expect or want an answer to that.

Comment: Do ask about it! Just do it in a different topic (so to not mix things up) and with more details so we can help you more easily.